# Create previous/next html page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a series of pages named "page-1" "page-2" "page-3" ..."page-99". Is there a way to make a navigation so that whenever I click the "next" button it goes to the next page, and if I click "previous" it will go to the previous page depending on what the current page number is.  I was wondering if there is a javascript solution to this since I have never used PHP.

```html
<a href="#" id="next">next</a> <!--it will go to page-3-->
<a href="#" id="prev">previous</a> <!--it will go to page-1-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started (starting with your original code).

```js
$('a[class^=page]').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var num = this.className.split('-')[1]; //2
   var nav = $(this).attr('data-nav');
   if (nav == 'next'){
         num = parseInt(num)+1;
         //window.location.href = "page-"+num+'.html';
   }else{
         num--;
         //window.location.href = "page-"+num+'.html';
   }
  alert('Navigating to: [ page-' +num+ '.html ]');
});
```

```css
a{padding:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:5px;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="page-2" data-nav="next">next</a> <!--it will go to page-3-->
<a href="#" class="page-2" data-nav="prev">previous</a> <!--it will go to page-1-->
```

---

Of course, this would be easier:

```js
$('a[class^=page]').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var num = this.className.split('-')[1]; //2
  
   //window.location.href = "page-"+num+'.html'; //The "real" code
  alert('Navigating to: [ page-' +num+ '.html ]'); //For demo purposes only
});
```

```css
a{padding:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:5px;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="page-1" >next</a> <!--it will go to page-3-->
<a href="#" class="page-3" >previous</a> <!--it will go to page-1-->
```

And this would be easiest (using the file name):

```js
//className *starts with* nav-
$('[class^=nav-]').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var fileName = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
   var fileName = 'http://page-2.html'; //FOR DEMO ONLY
      //alert(fileName); //should respond page2.html
   var num = fileName.split('-')[1]; //2
   var nav = this.className.split('-')[1]; //next
   if (nav == 'next'){
         num = parseInt(num)+1;
         //window.location.href = "page-"+num+'.html';
   }else{
         num = parseInt(num)-1;
         //window.location.href = "page-"+num+'.html';
   }

alert('Navigating to: [ page-' +num+ '.html ]'); //For demo purposes only

});
```

```css
a{padding:10px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:5px;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="nav-next" >next</a> <!--it will go to page-3-->
<a href="#" class="nav-prev" >previous</a> <!--it will go to page-1-->
```

Comment: You're right, I did not see the tag! The conversion to straight es5 is trivial and wouldn't contribute much as an independent solution.

Comment: @gibberish 
Would I have to change the class every time I add a page?
Thanks

Comment: It seems like in this case I would have to change the fileName on every page.

Comment: No, try it. It gets the filename from the file on the server. For *exactly* this code to work, you would have to save your pages with the names `page-3.html`, `page-5.html`, etc.

Comment: It does not work. The only time it works is when I am on page-2 and I have fileName='page-2.html' in the script. I am not sure why.

Comment: Comment out the `window.location.href` line and use the alert instead so you can see what page is attempted, then type that address manually into the address bar. That should reveal the problem...?

Comment: Thanks for making me think sir! I am a noob and I fixed this. Great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `PHP` or `JS`. But in either case you first need to be able to programmatically determine the page number of the currently displayed page.

You mention `PHP`, is this `WordPress` or some other similar `CMS`?

Okay so you mentioned that this is a basic website, but we still need to be able to pull that currentPageID. We could do this a few ways, the coolest would probably be to take it from the url, so let's do that.

To get the number from the url structure you mention in comments `(hostname.com/page-1.html)`:

```
// Let's first grab the url and pull just the last segment, in case there are numbers anywhere else in the url.
var url = window.location.href;
var array = url.split('/');
var lastSegmentOfUrl = array[array.length-1];

// Next, let's regex that last segment for the first number or group of numbers
var reg = /\d+/;
var currentPageID = lastSegmentOfUrl.match(r); // That's it!

// Then some basic math to get the next and previous page numbers
var previousPageID = currentPageID - 1;
var nextPageID = currentPageID + 1;

// And finally we change the href values on the next and previous <a> elements
document.getElementById('previous').href('/page-' + previousPageID + '.html');
document.getElementById('next').href('/page-' + nextPageID + '.html');
```

This will keep working forever assuming your url structure stays the same insofar as the last segment only has the current page number and no other numbers, and also that the next and previous anchor tags ID's don't change.

Comment: Jason,
This is not a CMS, I just want to make this for a basic website.

Comment: Okay I added a bit about retrieving the id from html, if you pass me your url structure I can maybe put together a simple regex to retrieve the current page number, but either solution should work.

Comment: hostname.com/page-1.html

Comment: okay, changed it around to use that instead. Now it requires no additional html or anything really.

Comment: Jason,
It seems like whenever I click "previous" or "next" it just adds a "#" at the end of the URL. am I doing something wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `location.pathname` and `String.prototype.replace`, no extra templating required!

**Update** Includes check that page exists before fetching.

```
// Check that a resource exists at url; if so, execute callback
function checkResource(url, callback){
    var check = new XMLHttpRequest();
    check.addEventListener("load", function(e){
        if (check.status===200) callback();
    });
    check.open("HEAD",url);
    check.send();
}

// Get next or previous path
function makePath(sign){
    // location.pathname gets/sets the browser's current page
    return location.pathname.replace(
        // Regular expression to extract page number
        /(\/page\-)(\d+)/,
        function(match, base, num) {
            // Function to increment/decrement the page number
            return base + (parseInt(num)+sign);
        }
    );
}
function navigate(path){ location.pathname = path; }

var nextPath = makePath(1), prevPath = makePath(-1);

checkResource(nextPath, function(){
    // If resource exists at nextPath, add the click listener
    document.getElementById('next')
        .addEventListener('click', navigate.bind(null, nextPath));
});
checkResource(prevPath, function(){
    // If resource exists at prevPath, add the click listener
    document.getElementById('prev')
        .addEventListener('click', navigate.bind(null, prevPath));
});
```

Note that this will increment the "`page-n`" portion of the path, even if you are in a sub-path. It will also work for non-html extensions.

E.g.,:

`mysite.com/page-100/resource` => `mysite.com/page-101/resource`

or

`mysite.com/page-100.php` => `mysite.com/page-101.php`

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. Do you know a way to make a stopper so that whenever there is no more pages it would stop navigating?

Comment: @Grigori A general solution to the question, "how to I verify that a resource exists before fetching it?" would be to send an HTTP `HEAD` request using `XMLHttpRequest`, and check whether the response fails with code `404` (not found) or succeeds with code `200`. I will update my answer to include this check.

Comment: I noticed that it does not work Chrome. In Mozilla though it works but once I reach the last page I would not be able to go back.

Comment: @Grigori This code is written in plain es3 and should work identically in all browsers. If you need help debugging your code you will need to provide more information, including any `console` messages.